# JNDI lookup fails for Glassfish custom resources

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi

I am new to Java EE 6 and JNDI so please forgive me if my problem seems trivial

I have added a custom resource to Glassfish 3.1.2 JNDI resources via tha admin console:

CommonTasks->Resources->JNDI->Custom Resources

- JNDI Name: someNumber
- Resource Type: java.lang.Integer
- Factory Class: org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory
- Additional Properties: [Name: digit; Value: 6]

Now I wish to look this resource up in my Java EE app I deploy to the glassfish server as ear.
I've tried this with no luck:

```
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();     
    Object o =  ctx.lookup("someNumber");
```

I keep getting a **NameNotFoundException**.
Can you tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong? I know that you can pass an environment hashtable to the initial context constructor with a provider URL - is this the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a rookie mistake.

Turns out the NameNotFoundException was actually caused by my integer jndi resource not having a value,
I was stupid to think that the Additional Properties are custom like in a JMS message and I could look them up later after fetching the object. The "Additional Properties" is were I had to input the "value" property. After making this change everything works smoothly